# How to check that a process is running under specific Windows user with Zabbix

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I wonder if it's possible to monitor if a Windows application is running under specific user or not.
Let's say there are 2 Win users (accounts) on the server:
User 1 has application.exe running all the time and I don't need to monitor it as it's being used by stuff;
User 2 should have the same application.exe to be running but since no one will use it I need Zabbix to monitor and alert if it's not launched.
Normally you would monitor if application is running via following trigger:

```
{HOST_NAME:proc_info[TestProcess.exe,wkset,sum].last(#1)}<1
```

So my question is if it's possible to monitor if application.exe is running under specific Win user or not. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `system.run[]` key using Powershell.

First you need to put in your agent configuration file `EnableRemoteCommands=1`. After that you need to restart the "Zabbix Agent" service.

Next step is just create new item with parameters:

> Type: `Zabbix agent`
>
> Key (ex. cmd): `system.run[powershell.exe -nolog -command "(Get-Process -Name cmd -IncludeUserName | Format-Table -Autosize)"]`
>
> Type of information: `Text`

Effect:
[image]

Next you can use item Preprocessing, and in Javascript display the desired data. Then just create a trigger that will check if the data is consistent.